# How do I flatten a featuretools entity set to get wide input format?

Tags: featuretools

I have an entity set with relations defined. Is there a method to get a left joined version of all the data frames in entities as we already have relations?

I can merge the dataframes outside using pandas but would like to leverage well defined entityset.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality does not currently exist in Featuretools. You can do it outside of Featuretools (with pandas).
Feel free to create an issue for this feature:

- https://github.com/alteryx/featuretools/issues/new/choose